# iPhone: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, subview

I try to set two different views into a subview, according to the state of a SegmentSwitcher:

```
if ([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == gameIndex) {
    if (self.gameView.view == nil) {
        GameView *gameV = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameView" bundle:nil];
        self.gameView = gameV;
        [gameV release];
    }
    [tableView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [subView insertSubview:gameView.view atIndex:0];
} else {
    if (self.tableView.view == nil) {
        TableView *tableV = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
        self.tableView = tableV;
        [tableV release];
    }
    [tableView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [subView insertSubview:tableView.view atIndex:0];
}
```

TableView extends TableViewController, but I always get the following error when I try to switch to the tableview:

2010-01-06 19:55:00.871 Handball[84675:40b] *** -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b18360
2010-01-06 19:55:00.873 Handball[84675:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b18360'
2010-01-06 19:55:00.874 Handball[84675:40b] Stack: (

Any help would be REALLY, REALLY appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `tableV` is declared to be a `TableView`, it's most likely initialized with a simple `UIViewConrtoller`, as it appears in your code.  Try changing the line to:

```
TableView *tableV = [[TableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
```

And `TableView` should be a subtype of `UITableViewController`.

By the way, the same should probably happen with `GameView` as well.

Comment: Can someone be that silly...? THANKS A LOT, of course that's it... you saved my day...

Comment: oh, please say controller and not conrtoller, it can save so many errors =D